# Get HTML Element on Angular Controller Load

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I simply want to access my HTML div element "myDigramDiv" from within my controller so that I can initialize it as a GoJS graph like this:

```
var graph = go.GraphObject.make;
var myDiagram: go.Diagram =
  graph(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", {
    initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center, // center Diagram contents
    "undoManager.isEnabled": true // enable Ctrl-Z to undo and Ctrl-Y to redo
  });
```

I have tried many SO suggestions on how to call  a function once the myDiagramDiv is ready. The methods I've tried are listed below. NONE of them are able access to myDiagramDiv through either the GoJS graph initialization code OR  $("myDiagramDiv").get() (jQuery). But I CAN access the element and through either of these methods when I simply put them in my "cancel" function, which fires on a button click within the dialog.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
});

$(function() {
  console.log("ready!");
});

$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
  console.log("ready!");
});

// ng-init function associated with myDiagramDiv
$scope.diagramInit = function() {
  console.log("ready!");
};

$scope.cancel = function() {
  var graph = go.GraphObject.make;
  var myDiagram: go.Diagram =
    graph(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv", {
      initialContentAlignment: go.Spot.Center, // center Diagram contents
      "undoManager.isEnabled": true // enable Ctrl-Z to undo and Ctrl-Y to redo
    });
};
```

And here is myDiagramDiv:

```
<div id="myDiagramDiv" ng-init="diagramInit()" style="width:900px; height:600px; background-color: #DAE4E4;">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I feel like I must be close and also doing something silly to not be able to manipulate my DOM element anywhere but a button callback.

Comment: Controllers shouldn't access the DOM really, that's more a job for directive which do receive the DOM element making it easy to access.

Comment: @GilesC you're totally right, but given time constraints and the structure of the project I'm working on, being able to get this one reference to the DOM in the controller is preferable.

Comment: As GillesC stated, you should be in a directive. If the DOM element hasn't been loaded yet, you can wrap your code in a $timeout.

Comment: @KFE that looks like a simple "x amount of time" timeout callback, is that right? I would prefer to fire off a function when I know my element has loaded. If what I'm describing isn't possible without a directive, then I will try pursuing that, but I would prefer to just reference the the one graph div for initialization purposes from the controller.

Comment: The timeout did work though. Thanks for that suggestion! Hmm really wish there was a better way to get a hold of it. Is there an explanation for why the other methods, which are documented all over the place, wouldn't be working for me?

Comment: @ThePartyTurtle I wish I knew more about Angular to reliably your question. Pretty sure you can set $timeout to 0 which will fire as soon as everything is ready to go.

Comment: I'm going to try that out, thanks! I think the main issue is Angular really doesn't want me to do what I'm doing so it's not making it easy to find out when everything is "ready to go". I'm writing demo quality code in a time pinch, so I'm thankful $timeout works decently.